# Connection specific DNS suffix has been changed

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I have two azure hosted Virtual Machines one containing a TIBCO installation and the other containing an Oracle database. In the TNSNAME.ORA file and the LISTENER.ORA the value is as follows:

HOST = servername.servername.f10.internal.cloudapp.net

This was obtained from ipconfig /all at the time of creation but this now seems to have changed and the connection specific DNS value is now set to reddog.microsoft.com with the hostname being set to servername and primary dns suffix being set to company.local

We have not made any changes to this environment, is it possible that this has been changed due to some sort of redeployment by microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Could you change it back manually?

Then please try to run a tool named [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to check if any process changes these settings.

Just specify the path of these settings, any operation involving these paths will be logged. (Please remember check the option "Drop Filtered Events", otherwise, there will be too many events logged.)

[image]

In case you may need, here is the path of connection specific DNS suffix:

**HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{GUID}\Domain**